# Looping over data frames in a list

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create a new logical variable (transfer) indicating whether or not each element of a vector (mrn) is present among 6 data frames. I have the 6 data frames in a list called transfers. The code below does what I want, but it is inefficient.

```
mer_tpa1520 <- mer_tpa1520 %>% 
  mutate(transfer = ifelse(mrn %in% transfers[[1]]$`MRN #` | 
                              mrn %in% transfers[[2]]$`MRN #` |
                              mrn %in% transfers[[3]]$`MRN #` |
                              mrn %in% transfers[[4]]$`MRN #` |
                              mrn %in% transfers[[5]]$`MRN #` |
                              mrn %in% transfers[[6]]$`MRN #`,
                            TRUE, FALSE))
```

I tried to achieve this with the code below without any success. The if statement is not vectorized and I couldn't figure out how to make it work with ifelse.

```
for (i in 1:length(transfers)){
    if(mer_tpa1520$mrn %in% transfers[[i]]$`MRN #`){
           mer_tpa1520$transfer <- TRUE
    }
  }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if you don't need this particular structure for your data (list of data.frames):

```
# bind all data frames in the list. 
# The name of each item in the original list is saved in the new columns "data.frame.name"

df <- bind_rows(transfers, .id = "data.frame.name")
```

Now this should be easier, although I'm not sure it is efficient in the sense you need.

```
# Creating a new "transport" variable in mer_tpa1520
mer_tpa1520$transfer <- mer_tpa1520$mrn %in% df$`MRN #`
```